# Extension of functional calculus of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, self-adjoint-operators

On [Reed & Simon's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125850506), we can find the following theorem, which is called the *continuous functional calculus*.

**Notation:** $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of the operator $A$, $\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})$ is the space of all bounded linear maps on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and $C(\sigma(A))$ is the space of all continuous functions defined on $\sigma(A)$.

**Theorem:** Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Then there exists a unique map $\phi: C(\sigma(A)) \to \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})$ with the following properties:

(a) $\phi$ is an algebraic $*$-homomorphism, that is:
$$\phi(fg) = \phi(f)\phi(g) \quad \phi(\lambda f) = \lambda \phi(f) \quad \phi(1) = I \quad \mbox{and} \quad \phi(\bar{f}) = \phi(f)^{*}$$

(b) $\phi$ is continuous, that is, $||\phi(f)||_{\mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})} \le C||f||_{\infty}$ for some $C>0$.

(c) If $f(x) = x$ then $\phi(A) = A$.

(d) If $A\psi = \lambda \psi$, then $\phi(f)\psi = f(\lambda)\psi$, $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$,

(e) $\sigma[\phi(f)] = \{f(\lambda): \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$

(f) If $f \ge 0$ then $\phi(f) \ge 0$

(g) $||\phi(f)|| = ||f||_{\infty}$.

The proof of this theorem is given by the authors and I have no problem with it.

Later in the book, the authors discuss the extension of this theorem for bounded Borel measurable functions. In this latter case, $\phi$ is now a map $\hat{\phi}: B(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{H})$, where $B(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of all bounded Borel measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. All properties (a) - (g) remain unchanged for $\hat{\phi}$. The discussion uses spectral measures to prove this Borel functional calculus. However, the authors state that *the Borel functional calculus can be proven directly by extending the above continuous functional calculus*.

**Question:** How do I extend the above stated continuous functional calculus to prove the Borel functional calculus? The authors give no hint on how to do it and I have no clue on how to approach such extension. By their comment, I'd expect that some natural extension exists but I couldn't even sketch one by myself.

Comment: See if you can use positivity and extend to intervals, and, finally, to Borel sets.

Comment: The extension $\hat \phi$ does not satisfy all properties (a)-(g). Both (e) and (g) fail in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let me recall the main theorems about the functional calculus in order to show which properties are needed for existence and uniqueness and which properties are consequences of the definition. The continous functional calculus states the following:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then
> there is a unique map
> $$\mathcal{P}_{A}:C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$$
> $$\hspace{4.7cm}f \mapsto \mathcal{P}_{A}(f)=:f(A)$$ called
> "continuous functional calculus of $A$", such that the following
> properties are fulfilled for all $f,g\in C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$ and
> $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$:
>
> 1. $\operatorname{id}_{\sigma(A)}(A)=A$ and $1(A)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{H}}$, where $1$ denotes the constant
>    $1$-function.
> 2. $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ is continuous.
> 3. $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ is a "$\star$-algebra homomorphism", which means that it is  an alegbra homomorphism, i.e. $$(\lambda
>     f+g)(A)=\lambda f(A) + g(A)$$ multiplicative, i.e. $$(f\cdot
>    g)(A)=f(A)g(A)$$ and the adjoint-operation commutes with
>    complex-conjugation, i.e. $$\overline{f}(A)=f(A)^{\ast}.$$

To proof this, one first of all defines the map for polynomials in the obvious way and then extends the construction to all continous functions via the Weierstrass approximation theorem. Now, using the above properties as well as the definition, one can show that the continous functional calculus has some further properties:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then
> the continous functional calculus $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ has the following
> additional properties:
>
> 1. $\Vert f(A)\Vert = \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$.
> 2. If $f\geq 0$ then $f(A)$ is a positive operator.
> 3. If $A\psi=\lambda\psi$ then $f(A)\psi=f(\lambda)\psi$.
> 4. $\sigma(f(A))=f(\sigma(A))$.

Now, let us extend this construction to the more general case of measurable functions:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then
> there is a unique map
> $$\mathcal{P}_{A}:\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$$
> $$\hspace{4.7cm}f \mapsto \mathcal{P}_{A}(f)=:f(A)$$ called
> "measurable functional calculus of $A$", such that the following
> properties are fulfilled for all $f,g\in C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$ and
> $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$:
>
> 1. $\operatorname{id}_{\sigma(A)}(A)=A$ and $1(A)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal{H}}$, where $1$ denotes the constant
>    $1$-function.
> 2. $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ is continuous.
> 3. $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ is a "$\star$-algebra homomorphism" as above.
> 4. Let $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence s.t. $f_{n}(t)\to f(t)$ for all $t\in\sigma(A)$ for some $f\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$. Then $\langle f_{n}(A)\varphi,\psi\rangle\to \langle f(A)\varphi,\psi\rangle$ for all $\varphi,\psi\in\mathcal{H}$.

In the special case of $f\in C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})\subset\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$, the uniqueness of the functional calculus is garantueed by the properties 1.-3. Now, it is important to note that for uniqueness in the general case, we also need the 4. property.

To show existence, there are several possibilities. One option is to first of all use the continuous functional calculus above to construct a set of measures. Let $f\in C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$. Then we define maps $l_{\varphi,\psi}(f):=\langle f(A)\varphi,\psi\rangle$. Using this, we define maps $l_{\varphi,\psi}:C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$, which are linear and also continuous, since
$$\vert l_{\varphi,\psi}(f)\vert\leq \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}\cdot \Vert\varphi\Vert\cdot\Vert\psi\Vert.$$
Hence, by the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) , there are complex measures $\mu_{\varphi,\psi}$ such that
$$\langle f(A)\varphi,\psi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(A)}\,f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{\varphi,\psi}.$$
Now, the main point is that the right-hand side of this equation is also meaningful for $f\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$ and hence, we can use this measures to define the functional calculus for Borel-measurable functions. More precisely, we define for all $f\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$ the map
$$(\varphi,\psi)\mapsto \int_{\sigma(A)}\,f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{\varphi,\psi},$$
which clearly is a continuous sesquilinearform. Hence, we can use the [theorem of Lax-Milgram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation) (basically a similar statement as the theorem of Frechet-Riesz but for sesquilinear forms), which shows that there exists an operator, which we denote by $f(A)$, such that
$$\langle f(A)\varphi,\psi\rangle=\int_{\sigma(A)}\,f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{\varphi,\psi}.$$
Using this definition, it is straight-forward to verify properties 1. - 4. above. Furthermore, it is also clear the the measurable functional calculus reduces to the continuous functional calculus in the case we take a function $f\in C(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})\subset\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$.

As before, there are some immediate consequences of this definition:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then
> the continous functional calculus $\mathcal{P}_{A}$ has the following
> additional properties:
>
> 1. The defining property 4. can be improved: Let $(f_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})^{\mathbb{N}}$
>    be a bounded sequence s.t. $f_{n}(t)\to f(t)$ for all $t\in\sigma(A)$
>    for some $f\in\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A),\mathbb{C})$. Then $\Vert
>     f_{n}(A)\psi\Vert\to\Vert f(A)\psi\Vert$ for all $\psi\in\mathcal{H}$.
> 2. $\Vert f(A)\Vert\leq \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask question, if something is unclear! :-)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have one question. The continuity of the map $(\varphi, \psi) \mapsto \int_{\sigma(A)} f\ d\mu_{\varphi, \psi}$ is not clear to me. If possible, can you add a few lines? Thank you.

Comment: For $f \in \mathcal{C}(\sigma(A), \mathbb{R})$ we have $\langle f(A) \varphi, \psi \rangle =  \int_{\sigma(A)} f \mathrm{d} \mu_{\varphi, \psi}$ and hence, with $f(x)=1$ we get $\langle \varphi, \psi \rangle= \int_{\sigma(A)} 1 \mathrm{d} \mu_{\varphi, \psi} = \mu_{\varphi, \psi} (\sigma(A))$. Thus, by Cauch-Schwarz applied to the LHS, we have $|\mu_{\varphi, \psi} (\sigma(A))| \leq \|\varphi\| \| \psi\|$.

Comment: Using this, we can show that the map $(\varphi, \psi) \mapsto \int_{\sigma(A)}f \mathrm{d} \mu_{\varphi, \psi}$ is bounded and hence continuous, since $\| \int_{\sigma(A)}f \mathrm{d} \mu_{\varphi, \psi} \| \leq \| f\|_{\infty}\int_{\sigma(A)} \mathrm{d} \mu_{\varphi, \psi} \|\leq \|f\|_{\infty} \|\varphi \| \|\psi\|$.

Comment: The only thing I'm unsure is, how to argue that $\|f\|_{\infty} < \infty$ for $f \in \mathcal{B}(\sigma(A), \mathbb{C}) \setminus \mathcal{C}(\sigma(A), \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess going for all measurable functions might be a bit too ambitious. Perhaps one can only do it for bounded measurable functions (which is pretty good for most applications).

Comment: @bayes2021  Indeed, $\mathcal{B}$ in my notation above means "bounded and measruable". You can in fact extend the functional calculus to unbounded measurable functions: Every measurable bounded function $f$ can be approximated point-wise by a sequence $f_{n}$ of bounded ones. Then you set $x\in\mathcal{D}(f(A))$ if any only if $f_{n}(A)x$ converges in the Hilbert space and define $f(A)x$ to be its limit. However, in this way, $f(A):\mathcal{D}(f(A))\to\mathcal{H}$ is in general an unbounded operator. As a matter of fact, $f(A)$ is bounded if and only if $f\in L^{\infty}(\sigma(A),\mu^{A})$.

Comment: *every measurable UNbounded function $f$ can be approximated point-wise by a sequence $f_{n}$ of bounded ones

Comment: Maybe as a suggestion: Two books which deal in very much details with the general case of unbounded operators $A$ and unbounded functions $f$ are for example the book of Moretti "spectral theory and quantum mechanics" as well as the monography "unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces" by Schmüdgen

Comment: @G.Blaickner How do we prove the properties of the measurable functional calculus? I think I've read somewhere that every (bounded?) Borel measurable  function is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. If that's the case we could use the dominated convergence theorem to establish convergence in the weak operator topology. Am I right with these considerations?

Comment: @bayes2021 yes, thats right. It is proven with dominant convergence.

Comment: Do you know a reference which justifies this, aka. why can we approximate Borel measurable functions by continuous ones? Couldn‘t find one.

Comment: @bayes2021 First, it is important to stress that this is only true for Bore measurable functions on *compact* sets, like the spectrum of a bounded operator. I know a reference in a book called "Funktionalanalysis" by D. Werner, however, it is only available in german. I would bet that you can find a proof also in the first volume of Reed-Simon, but I don't have it around me right now. Otherwise, this question might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481619/are-bounded-borel-functions-on-a-compact-set-the-pointwise-limit-of-continuous-f

Comment: Fortunately I speak german;)